# Start Docker Container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to start a docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/parrotstream/hbase/)
on Windows 10 with

```
docker-compose -p parrot up
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

Executing the command in the directory with the docker image in it does not work either. 
I am new to using Docker and I am unsure how to start the container. According to the Docker Hub page of the image, this is all I have to do. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Edit:

As pointed out by the replies, I've downloaded the folder from github, including the docker-compose.yml. I am currently getting an error because of my permission.

```
ERROR: for hbase  Cannot start service hbase: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint hbase (5fb66c3b2b0d3092edce09f03cc803cc3ea447c07a1a2135271238de626458c6): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080: unexpected error Permission denied
ERROR: for hbase  Cannot start service hbase: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint hbase (5fb66c3b2b0d3092edce09f03cc803cc3ea447c07a1a2135271238de626458c6): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080: unexpected error Permission denied
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Do I have a wrong configuration in docker?

Comment: you need to create a docker-compose.yml

Comment: Make sure that there is no other application listening on port 8080 and that you are spawning the containers with a user that has sufficient permissions. Also, open a new question when your original one has been answered and now differs too much from the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual `docker-compose.yml` that you are looking for may be the one hosted in their github repo found [here](https://github.com/parrot-stream/docker-hbase).

```
version: '3'
services:
  hbase:
    container_name: hbase
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: parrotstream/hbase:latest
    external_links:
    - hadoop
    - zookeeper
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 8085:8085
    - 9090:9090
    - 9095:9095
    - 60000:60000
    - 60010:60010
    - 60020:60020
    - 60030:60030
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: parrot_default
```

By default, `docker-compose` tries to read the configuration from a file  named `docker-compose.yml` within you current working directory. You could override this behavior with `docker-compose -f <anotherfile.yml>`.

```
Options:
  -f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose file
                              (default: docker-compose.yml)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. But I am currently getting a different error, after downloading the file from github. I've written it in my post

Answer (score 0):

Yes, command needs a compose file and the readme assumes that you have a docker-compose.yml in the directory where you execute the command.

You can find one in the linked repository from DockerHub [parrot-stream/docker-hbase](https://github.com/parrot-stream/docker-hbase)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a docker-compose file as follows

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '2'
services:
  parrot:
    image: parrotstream/hbase
```

then you can create a build and run is using

`docker-compose build parrot # build image`

`docker-compose up parrot # run`